# Select data from a table and change how it is shown based on the data

Tags: sql

I have a table, `IHE_ISSUES` and a table, `ISSUE_QUARTER`. I want to select the data from `ISSUE_QUARTER` that has a value that is “Fall”, “Summer”, “Spring”, or “Winter”, and if it is “Winter”, make it return “1/1/*issue_year*” instead of “Winter” followed by the issue year. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Case

```
Select Case issue when 'Winter' then '1/1/' || issue_year 
            when 'Spring' then '4/1/' || issue_year
            when 'Summer'....
       End IssueDate
From IHE_ISSUES;
```

Comment: when i enter this and add fall and date for summer it does not work gives me ORA-00905: missing keyword error any help

Comment: yep forgot the End added it to the answer.

Comment: Select Case issue when 'Winter' then '1/1/' + issue_year 
            when 'Spring' then '4/1/' + issue_year
            when 'Summer' then '6/1/' + issue_year 
            when 'fall' then '9/1/' 
            from IHE_ISSUES
       End is my full code it still doesent work any help?

Comment: The from clause is outside the case-End.  Updated answer

Comment: it gives me a ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR error

Comment: it worked but the tables name is CASEISSUE_QUARTERWHEN'WINTER'THEN'1/1/'||ISSUE_YEARWHEN'SPRING'THEN'4/1/'||ISSUE_YEARWHEN'SUMMER'THEN'6/1/'||ISSUE_YEARWHEN'FALL'THEN'9/1/'||ISSUE_YEAREND

Comment: how would i fix this?

Comment: Alias it.  Easy, I'll make another modification to the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58389/discussion-between-user3841039-and-bowlturner).